# Use async delegate inside synchronous method

Tags: c#, async-await, delegates, task, task-parallel-library

I'm quite not sure about underlying behavior in this case:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        Method(async () => await Task.Delay(10000));
    }

    public void Method(Action action)
    {
        action();
    }
```

A created delegate uses async/await machinery, but inside `Method`, `action` is called synchronisly and even there is no way to call it in async manner since this delegate doesn't return `Task`. So why it's even possible to generate async definition for this delegate? At first glance, only code like:

```
    Method(() => Thread.Sleep(10000));
```

should be allowed. What did I miss?

Comment: Somewhat related: [How do I avoid async void lambdas when I'm not the author of the method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295163/how-do-i-avoid-async-void-lambdas-when-im-not-the-author-of-the-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda expression is being converted into an async void method which has no return value. You can prove this by writing it out:

```
static async void Foo()
{
}

static async Task Bar()
{
}

public void Test()
{
    Method(Foo);  //Works
    Method(Bar);  //Compilation error
}
```

This means it will run as a "fire and forget" call.

It's worth noting that `async void` is best avoided except for specific cases. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12144426/2791540).

Comment: How does that code "prove" it?

Comment: `async void` is not fire-and-forget, it's [fire-and-crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659603/async-void-asp-net-and-count-of-outstanding-operations/17660475#17660475). Any error is rethrown in the captured synchronization context, which usually terminates the process.