# Alternative to Timer that takes an async function?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, timer

At the moment I have a regular `System.Threading.Timer` that calls an async lambda function:

```cs
_ = new Timer(async _ =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
});
```

(*Clarification due to confusion in the comment section: The `Task.Delay(1000)` is only an example of an async function call. In my actual code I am performing an asynchronous HTTP request. But this question applies to any async operation, regardless if it is an IO operation, HTTP request, database call, etc.*)

But Rider gives the warning:

> Avoid using 'async' lambda when delegate type returns 'void'

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image: Screenshot of Rider giving the warning "Avoid using 'async' lambda when delegate type returns 'void'"]

I read on https://stackoverflow.com/a/70295788/595990:

> The way to avoid using an async lambda is obvious: don't use an async lambda. Just because the compiler allows you to pass an async lambda everywhere an `Action` is expected, doesn't mean that you should.

Is there an alternative to `Timer` in .NET 7 that expects an async function, to avoid this warning?

Comment: Why use a timer to run an asynchronous function?

Comment: That's just a warning. You can rewrite the lambda to not to use `async/await` but attach continuations to tasks with `.ContinueWith()`. This way your lambda would return `void`. The readablity of the code suffers, though.

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: @shingo Maybe they need to use `HttpClient` in a timer, or do something with a database. There are plenty of reasons why one might need to do async work inside a timer.

Comment: Are you OK with allowing overlapping executions of the asynchronous lambda? This can happen in case the duration of the asynchronous work is longer than the timer's interval.

Comment: Executions can overlap even with synchronous lambdas. From the docs : `The callback can be executed simultaneously on two thread pool threads if the timer interval is less than the time required to execute the callback`.

Comment: The warning is issued because the callback is essentially an `async void` that can't be awaited. If you don't care about overlapping executions you can ignore it. If you do care though, you should use [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-7.0) and its [WaitForNextTickAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer.waitfornexttickasync?view=net-7.0#system-threading-periodictimer-waitfornexttickasync(system-threading-cancellationtoken)) method.

Comment: You really need to explain what you are actually trying to do. Using a `Task.Delay` inside a timer is kind of weird, since `Task.Delay` is essentially just a wrapper around a timer. Depending on your use case you might want either a [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-7.0) or a threading.Timer and call `.Change` manually to reset the timer.

Comment: @shingo @JonasH Sorry for being unclear. It's like @DavidG says, I want to do async operations inside the timer (an HTTP call in my actual code). The `Task.Delay` is just an example of an async call. Regardless what I await, Rider displays the same warning.

Comment: Now I have updated the question with a clarification. I hope this makes it easier to answer the question.

Comment: Do you care about overlapping callbacks? If you do, use PeriodicTimer. If not, you can ignore the warning, keeping in mind you're using an `async void` method.

Comment: Why is `_ = new Timer` used? That means the timer will get orphaned as soon as `Created` exits. The callback may never be called. Was this used to "simplify" the code or is this the actual code?

Comment: @DavidG IMO, timers themselves are already executed asynchronously. Using timers to execute an async method is like `new Thread(async () => { })`, which is legal but strange. To periodically run an async method, it should also be implemented (task-based) asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-7.0), e.g.

```
var timerTask = Task.Run(async () => {
  using PeriodicTimer timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

  while (true) {
    // Payload here
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync();
  }
});
```

**Edit:** Please, note it's just an answer for the question

> Is there an alternative to `Timer` ... to avoid the warning

If you want an *elaborated design* (say, you want to have a policy for *exceptions* in the payload, *very long* payload etc.), you should use something more powerful than a timer, e.g. [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) (Recurring Jobs)

Comment: If the payload task takes longer than the timer interval, then the next tick will not occur at the specified interval, but it's delayed by the delta between the interval and the payload task duration (effectively avoiding overlapping executions), isn't it?

Comment: @Julian: As far as I can see (we can put `3000` into the `Task.Delay` and see) the next tick will be just after the previous one (it's high time to call, we are even late). When payload is fast then timer adds a delay (not too frequent, `1000` ms before calls)

Comment: This approach has different behavior than the approach shown in the question. In case the payload fails once, the `timerTask` will silently fail and the payload will stop being invoked. On the contrary the approach in the question will react to a payload failure with the crashing of the process (which might be the desirable/preferable behavior).

Comment: @DmitryBychenko exactly, the next call will be late, which is what I mentioned - there will be a delta between ticks which is higher than the specified interval.

Comment: @Julian regarding the behavior of the `PeriodicTimer`, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval/62724908#62724908 "Run async method regularly with specified interval").

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That confirms my point, the way I see it. Thanks for the link.